# http error 500 on require_once in Child Theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting an error 500 and i don't know why this is happening.
I'm building a wordpress child theme with the function file including two strings of "require_once" function to replace some php files of main theme.

```
 require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/first path');
 require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/second path');
```

Everything works as intended using only the first path.

Using both or only the second, results in an error 500.

Both paths are correct with the same permissions, there is no error in the htaccess and i don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the [debug log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) yet?

Comment: not yet, i just set to true the debug mode.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare thim_login_popup_widget() (previously declared in path-child/inc/widgets/login-popup/login-popup.php:218) in maintheme/inc/widgets/login-popup/login-popup.php on line 218

Comment: As the error message states, the `thim_login_popup_widget()` function has been declared twice. You'll need to fix that.